# check my array if the route element exist in my array

Tags: javascript, express, crud

- Set up the basis for CRUD

```
const movies = { title: 'Jaws', year: 1975, rating: 8 },{ title: 'Avatar', year: 2009, rating: 7.8 },{ title: 'Brazil', year: 1985, rating: 8 },{ title: 'The Shaw shank', year: 1992, rating: 6.2 }
```

With Express, make it so that when the URL /movies/read is requested, you answer with

```
{status:200, data:\<MOVIES\> }
```

where `\<MOVIES\>` is the list of movies    i tried to put if condition but not work with me

Comment: - Set up the basis for CRUD

   const movies = [
       { title: 'Jaws', year: 1975, rating: 8 },
       { title: 'Avatar', year: 2009, rating: 7.8 },
       { title: 'Brazil', year: 1985, rating: 8 },
       { title: ' The shaw shank', year: 1992, rating: 6.2 }
   ]
   ```
- With Express, make it so that when the url `/movies/read` is requested, you answer with `{status:200, data:<MOVIES> }` where `<MOVIES>` is the list of movies

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.